# Web3.js is taking lot of time to return a promise

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, etherscan

Web3 is taking time near about 5 minutes even after the transaction got `3 confirmations` to return a promise from a smart contract which is deployed on kovan testnet. Please give some suggestion how to overcome this problem.

```
async uploadData() {
      const account = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      const exists = await this.isRecorded(this.hash);

      if (exists) {
        alert("Document Already Signed");
      } else {
        await instance.methods
          .signDoc(
            this.hash,
            this.notaryForm.email,
            this.notaryForm.partyA,
            this.notaryForm.partyB
          )
          .send({ from: account[0] });
        alert("Successfully Signed the Document");
      }
    },
```

Comment: Increase the gas-price.

Comment: @goodvibration No, I said, I'm getting the confirmations within a second, but it takes a long time to return `receipt` as a promise.

Comment: What you're describing doesn't make sense. You can either `await` for the receipt, or you can use a callback function for the receipt and a callback function for the confirmations. In the first method, confirmations are not even received. In the second method, the receipt is always received before (or perhaps with) the first confirmation. You, as reflected in your code, are using the first method, so I don't understand how you can claim that you've received any confirmations to begin with.

Comment: BTW, the only thing that you get instantly is the transaction hash (not the receipt nor the confirmations). But that, just like the confirmations, can only obtained via a callback function (and not via `await`, which is what you seem to be using).

Comment: @goodvibration But I'm getting nothing in the `console.log()` for about 3-4 minutes. After 3-4 minutes I'm getting that promise `receipt`. Is it related to infura web socket because i have not set that up yet.

Comment: Well, you claim to be getting confirmations - how exactly, and where is that shown in your code???

Comment: By confirmation I mean, that particular transaction's confirmations on the etherscan

Comment: Well then it sounds like the problem is in the connection between etherscan and your node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try rewriting your code using `.on()`.
Find some explanations [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/web3-eth-contract.html#id22) and see the Examples section.